# What causes the 2 Party System (Australia)

Tags: parties, government, australia

In Australian Politics, why is the parliament only ever controlled by either a Labour or Liberal party? Is it possible for a minority party to be elected? i.e. could we have a Family First Prime Minister?

Comment: There's always a possibility for anything. Quantum physics dictates that. The question is whether it's even remotely likely.

Comment: The question is wrong in two points of fact.  Australia has something like a 2.75 party system.  And the most recent Labor (the correct spelling) government did not control parliament.  Almost no Australian government has recently controlled the Senate, and the prior Labor government didn't control the house of representatives.

Answer (score 4):

Their are a number of causes:

1. Psychologically it is easier for people to thinks in terms of duality ie good / bad. This is why we have a propensity for making extreme labels for our enemies  they are fascists of communists even when that is not true
2. Electoral systems with single person geographic representative electorates limit the number different political associations that can occur meaningfully.

eg 
While everybody has a different political perspective, a political party needs to span a range. This range becomes wider when it must span geographical areas that may have different issues.

To achieve governance a party must be represented in a majority of electorates, so area based political groups are marginalised if they can not achieve this, so logically they need to go into coalition with groups from other geographic areas, then efficiencies are achieved by coalescing.

The voting systems means politicians must have mass appeal, this is particularly true in Australia's preferential voting system, which in effect gives us the least disliked politician, as opposed to a first past the post system (eg UK ) which gives the most liked even if only 20% or 30% actually like them.

A party that appeals to significantly less than 50% of voters in a geographic area therefore must go into tactical coalition with other parties to gain power. From a political perspective it is more likely  that more power can be gained if 2 small parties merge to have a broader appeal.

3. Different voting systems are more likely to result in minor parities. Multi person electorates (as in Australian senate and Tasmania) and systems where people can vote for the party (Germany; where part of the vote goes to the party and part to a geographic area) . Under either of these system a party can survive and be represented on a smaller percentage of the vote than 50%. In Australia an upper house  senate seat is possible with a vote in the low teens – it varies.
4. For decades the major parties have spent considerable amounts on misinforming the electorate that a vote for a minor party is a wasted vote. This is patently untrue in a preferential system where even your second last preference has the same vote value as your first.
5. Tactically a minor party that has a geographic sustainability must go into coalition with another party to achieve governance. Hence the Nationals though a separate party are considered as a Liberals generally because they are in coalition perpetually. As such they gain political power but become unnoticed by many in the city.

There are Greens and independents in the lower house, so it is possible one of them could become prime minister, if they could get sufficient support from other parties – but extremely unlikely and there would need to be a major crisis.